# error creating KMS Key with terraform code with error message MalformedPolicyDocumentException

Tags: amazon-web-services

Whenever I run Terraform Apply to deploy the resources,I am getting this message:"error creating KMS Key: MalformedPolicyDocumentException: Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals".  How can I solve this problem please?I have looked at my Principal in my code and they all seem right to me ,so I do not know why its saying this message.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Key-default-1",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Sid":"Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":{
                "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:root"
            },
            "Action":"kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid":"Allow CloudTrail access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":{
                "Service":"cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action":"kms:DescribeKey",
            "Resource":"*"
        },{
            "Sid":"Allow Cloudtrail to encrypt logs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":{
                "Service":"cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action":"kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition":{
                "StringLike":{
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn":[
                        "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${var.organization_id}:trail/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid":" Allow Cloudtrail to decrypt logs",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal":{
                "AWS":"*"
            },
            "Action":"kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource":"*",
            "Condition":{
                "StringEquals":{
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "${var.organization_id}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid":"Allow AWS Config to encrypt/decrypt logs",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal":{
                "Service":"config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action":[
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource":"*"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: I would start by removing one statement at a time until you find the specific one causing the error. I imagine one of the variables doesn't have the appropriate value, but you need to do some basic debugging first to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove spaces and special characters from your Sids.

"The Sid element supports ASCII uppercase letters (A-Z), lowercase letters (a-z), and numbers (0-9)."